# How to insert value into table column?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am getting into SQL, trying to insert a value into a specific table column but it seems it only wants to take one character compared to the entire string I am attempting to supply it.

```
import sqlite3
import random

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"test.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
profile_ID = str(random.randint(100,999))

'''
insert into one column
'''
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Webstore(Running) VALUES(?)", (profile_ID))
```

this is the error that appears:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
> current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied.

It seems the insert with the query above only wants to accept one character versus the three in profile_ID, I attempt to send a string such as "string 6" and it would pass me the same error but "8 supplied" in this case (8 characters in "string 6").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert in using `sqlite`, but I firmly believe the problem you are sticking with is not related to this module; rather, it's a `tuple` issue. I believe you need to change this line:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Webstore(Running) VALUES(?)", (profile_ID))
```

to this line:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Webstore(Running) VALUES(?)", (profile_ID,))
```

There is a slight difference between these two lines. `(profile_ID)` has been changed to `(profile_ID,)`. The former could be anything based on the value of `profile_ID`: a string, an integer, or even a float. But the latter is absolutely a tuple which I believe you will need for the second variable in `cursor.execute`.

Answer (score 0):

inserting one value:

```
cursor.execute("insert into Webstore (Running) values (%s)" % profile_ID)
```

inserting multiple values (? works here without error):

```
cursor.execute("insert into Webstore (Running, Status) values (?, ?)", (profile_ID, status))
```